# Spring Boot DataSource

Tags: datasource, spring-boot

I was wondering if it is possible to make spring boot read datasource properties from gradle.properties file?

I don't want to put database credentials in application.properties (application.properties is checked in version control. We don't want to expose db info). Furthermore, our developers are not provided with test/staging db credentials. Currently, those values are read from ~/.gradle.properties file.

Comment: They aren't provided but they have a `~/.gradle.properties` which is readable... Not sure what you gain by that, but alas. You can make Spring Boot read the gradle.properties just specify it on the command line, or you can modify your build script to add everything from gradle.properties to the command line. Or just add an `application.properties` next to the artifact you are running it will be read next to the provided `application.properties`.

Comment: you can also enable an extra profile on your app (see `SpringApplication`), for instance, `secret` and have an `application-secret.properties` with those info. That's essentially the same advice as above except you're being explicit about it.

Comment: ~/.gradle.properties file reside in test/staging servers, which are only accessible by infrastructure team. Therefore, developers cannot access this file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try "--spring.config.location" command line switch as per [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)